# SQLite: Column 'date' does not belong to table

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database with following columns: _id, displayName, date

Using following csharp code i am trying to Select rows in Sqlite Database, it works for all columns but the date!:

```
    try
    {
    SQLiteConnection mDBConnection = 
    new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\x86\\Desktop\\db forms\\instances.db");
        mDBConnection.Open();

        SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(mDBConnection);
        mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT _id, displayName, datetime(date) FROM instances";
        SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        mDBConnection.Close();

        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
           string id = row["_id"].ToString();
           string displayName = row["displayName"].ToString();
           DateTime date = (DateTime)row["date"]; //Error Here: Column 'date' does not belong to table instances.
           string datefromDb = row["date"].ToString(); // Same Error with this line...
           MessageBox.Show(id + " " + displayName + " ");

        };            
        }



    catch (SQLiteException SqliteException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(SqliteException.ToString());
    }
```

I get this error: Column 'date' does not belong to table instances. The column 'date' actually does exists in the database. If i don't wrap date column in datetime(...)  it gives "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" at dt.Load(reader);

UPDATE: This is the database ... its columns and types.

[image: Database]

Date Data Inside Database.

[image: Data]

Comment: Maybe you need a alias like `datetime(date) as date`

Comment: Yes vendetta " datetime(date, 'localtime') as date " works, it returns date now, but exactly as desired i.e. 1387539933510 (just like they are saved in database). Any ideas about that?

Comment: what is the column data type of date column in your database?

Comment: its type is date and its name is also 'date'

Answer (score 2):

change your sql as below

```
  mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT _id, displayName, datetime(date) as date FROM instances";
```

otherwise your select statement return column name as `datetime(date)`, by using alias [`as date`] make sure that column name return from select query having column name as `date`

### Update:

```
  mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT _id, displayName, datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch') as date FROM instances";
```

Comment: Damith it works, it returns date now, however not in the right format, database dates are 13 digit time stamps e.g. 1387539933510 right now it returns something like: 1698789-19650109-20 -19:-12:-55, any ideas how i can get date value exactly as in my database? Thanks!

Comment: Now it returns 2013-12-20 11:45:33, that is correct YYYY MM DD HH:MM:SS Date Time, but still the need is unixepoch or the timestamp i.e. 1387539933510  like they are stored in database.

Answer (score 2):

Try use this:

```
mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT _id, displayName, datetime(date, localtime) date FROM instances";
```

instate of this line

```
mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT _id, displayName, datetime(date) FROM instances";
```

`localtime` will convert your `date` string into DateTime.

Comment: it works, but dates are not in proper format :( i.e. 1387539933510

Comment: @Ayub I dont know much more about SQLLite, but when I google then I find something which more relevant for u, check this link http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html . Accourding to it I modified my suggested answer check it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
    mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT _id, displayName, datetime(date) FROM instances";
```

does not match

```
       DateTime date = (DateTime)row["datetime(date)"]; //Error Here: Column 'date' does not belong to table instances.
       string datefromDb = row["datetime(date)"].ToString(); // Same Error with this line...
```

Make sure you use the name exact name of the column.

The comment above the 13 digit is a Unix time stamp and you are requesting a formatted date time.

Comment: I double checked that drhunn, no luck

Answer (score 1):

Replace your sql statement from this.

```
mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT _id, displayName, datetime(date) as date FROM instances";
```

Or

Replace

```
 DateTime date = (DateTime)row["date"];
```

from

```
 DateTime date = (DateTime)row["datetime(date)"];
```

Issue is you did not mentioned any alias in your sql query `datetime(date) as date` "**(as date)**" is the alias. so your query return the column name by default **datetime(date)**  . After mentioning alias your column name would be **date**

So you can use both logics in your code as mentioned above.

Comment: This works Shujaat, but my database date values are like: 1387539933510 it returns something like: 1698789-19650109-20 -19:-12:-55 for same value, is there a way i can get that in proper format?

Comment: string datefromDb = row["date"].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"); and DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(datefromDb);

Comment: Shujaat .toString method takes no argument. I need to get values same as database format i.e. 1387539933510 not in MM DD YYYY HH MM SS.