# Error Android Database SQL Lite because date

Tags: java, android, sql, date, syntax-error

why when I run the application there is an error like this? if there is something wrong with my application?

```
07-16 00:01:04.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 00:01:04.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1617): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.NoteList}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, body, date FROM notes
```

The application of NoteDbAdapter.java

---

```
import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotesDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "title text not null, body text not null, date text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long createNote(String title, String body, String date) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY,KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY,KEY_DATE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String body,String date) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);

        //This lines is added for personal reason
        args.put(KEY_DATE, date);

        //One more parameter is added for data
        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

The application of NoteList.java

---

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;

public class NoteList extends ListActivity {

    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private int mNoteNumber = 1;

    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_review);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter (this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();             
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        Button addnote = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addnotebutton);
        addnote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createNote();
                }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notelist_menu, menu);
        return true;        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_about:

               AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NoteList.this);
               dialog.setTitle("About");
               dialog.setMessage("Hello! I'm Heng, the creator of this application. This application is created based on learning." +
                    " Used it on trading or any others activity that is related to business is strictly forbidden."
                       +"If there is any bug is found please freely e-mail me. "+
                        "\n\tedisonthk@gmail.com"
                       );
               dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       dialog.cancel();

                   }
               });
               dialog.show();              
               return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

    private void createNote() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

    private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(notesCursor);


        String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE ,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DATE};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 ,R.id.date_row};

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.note_row, notesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();        
    }   

}
```

please help, there may be something wrong with my code,

Comment: I suggest that you connect to your device with ADB and check the database to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: @Ruhbi - did you try [searching for "SQLiteException no such column"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQLiteException+no+such+column) before posting this question?
Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779484/sqlite-column-date-does-not-belong-to-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling the app from the phone and then re-launching the application. This issue often occurs when building an android app, where you make a change to the database schema but forget to re-create the db.